# Custom PCB to switch on and off USB

Tags: transistors, mosfet, usb

I am trying to create a Raspberry Pi Hat which has my usb hub and a mosfet which turn on and off the power on individual port.

There are different way to do this: Transistor, Mosfet, Relay, but I have chosen Mosfet for the lower consumption if the usb has to be on for a long time ( everything runs on battery ).

Unfortunately my knowledge of mosfet made the pcb not working as I was hopping, so I tried to add a transistor PNP and buying different rate ( 500ma, 1A ), the transistor worked but didnt let pass enough current even if it says 1A.

I am a bit confused on what I have made wrong and if my idea to use the VCC rather than GND line is correct.
I do understand that PNP should be use on the positive line and NPN on negative lines, right?

This is my schematic:
[image]

My temporary solution is to connect a relay to switch on and off, which works, but I want to make my pcb as small as possible by using a mosfet ( smd ).

Answer (score 1):

Might want to swap the source and drain on those P channel mosfets, the source should connect to Vbus and the drain to the port (Otherwise the body diode will conduct).

Also what exact part number is the mosfet? You need a logic level part, because you only have 5V Vgs available.

Comment: I tried to use this mosfet [link](http://uk.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=15001&langId=44&urlRequestType=Base&partNumber=9103503&storeId=10151) but I suppose what you said  is that I cant trigger with a 3.3V.
In the other hand, I am using a expander IO which can operate at 5V, so I could potentially use that 5V output to connect my mosfet.

Comment: The mosfet will switch on if the gate is more then 500mV below the source, so you need 5V if you are switching a 5V rail. Pulling the gate low will switch on the mosfet.

Answer (score 1):

The P-Channel MOSFETs require a high side driver, since your GPIOs on the RPi can only go up to 3V3. You need to go up to 5V to switch the MOSFETs off completely.

Comment: So what is the alternative here? Transistor?

Comment: One N-Channel logic level mosfet and one resistor to drive the p-channel gate.

Comment: any suggestion? I think I need to find something which can handle up to 1A. I will try to find something and might post here to double check.

Comment: Sopping questions are off topic here.